# How to get streamline aggrid to reset the view of the data frame after button click

Tags: python, streamlit

So I'm making a streamlit application (an unsubscribe feature) and I want my users to be able to select the rows they want to unsubscribe from, then click a button to confirm.

I have a small working example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridUpdateMode, DataReturnMode
from st_aggrid.grid_options_builder import GridOptionsBuilder


def make_aggrid_table(data: pd.DataFrame, key: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    The function that creates the aggrid table. taken from the aggrid_example.py file.
    :param: data: dataframe of the interaction data
    :return: dataframe of the selected rows from the aggrid table
    """
    gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(data, min_column_width=100)
    gb.configure_default_column(wrapText=True, autoHeight=True)
    gb.configure_selection('multiple', use_checkbox=True,
                           groupSelectsChildren="Group checkbox select children")  # Enable multi-row selection
    gb.configure_side_bar()  # Add a sidebar
    grid_options = gb.build()

    grid_response = AgGrid(
        data,
        gridOptions=grid_options,
        data_return_mode=DataReturnMode.AS_INPUT,
        update_mode=GridUpdateMode.MODEL_CHANGED,
        fit_columns_on_grid_load=True,
        theme='dark',  # Add theme color to the table
        enable_enterprise_modules=True,
        height=370,
        reload_data=False,
        wrap_text=True,
        resizeable=True,
        key=key
    )
    grid_response_data = grid_response['data']
    selected = grid_response['selected_rows']
    df = pd.DataFrame(selected)  # Pass the selected rows to a new dataframe df
    return df

pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}, index=range(3)).to_csv('some_file.csv')
some_csv = pd.read_csv('some_file.csv', index_col=0)

selection = make_aggrid_table(some_csv, 'some_key')

if not selection.empty:
    print(selection)
    delete = st.button('Delete')
    if delete:
        for index, row in selection.iterrows():
            some_csv.drop(index, inplace=True, axis=0)
        some_csv.to_csv('some_file.csv')
```

At initialization, all looks good, the app has all three rows and all three entries in the CSV (pictured below)
[image: before delete button pressed]

but after I press delete, the CSV changes, but my view of the data does not.
(pictured below)
[image: After pressing delete]

This is causing issues with users 'double unsubscribing'. How should I structure my code so that the view changes after the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the aggrid creation out of the function seems to have done something, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what.

This seems to work:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridUpdateMode, DataReturnMode
from st_aggrid.grid_options_builder import GridOptionsBuilder


def on_delete():
    some_csv = pd.read_csv('some_file.csv', index_col=0).reset_index(drop=True)
    some_csv = some_csv.drop(selection.index)
    some_csv.to_csv('some_file.csv')
    print('got here')
# pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]}, index=range(3)).to_csv('some_file.csv')  # run once to get csv established

print('and down below')
some_csv = pd.read_csv('some_file.csv', index_col=0).reset_index(drop=True)
print(some_csv)
gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(some_csv, min_column_width=100)
gb.configure_default_column(wrapText=True, autoHeight=True)
gb.configure_selection('multiple', use_checkbox=True,
                       groupSelectsChildren="Group checkbox select children")  # Enable multi-row selection
gb.configure_side_bar()  # Add a sidebar
grid_options = gb.build()

grid_response = AgGrid(
    some_csv,
    gridOptions=grid_options,
    data_return_mode=DataReturnMode.AS_INPUT,
    update_mode=GridUpdateMode.MODEL_CHANGED,
    fit_columns_on_grid_load=True,
    theme='dark',  # Add theme color to the table
    enable_enterprise_modules=True,
    height=370,
    reload_data=False,
    wrap_text=True,
    resizeable=True
)
selected = grid_response['selected_rows']
selection = pd.DataFrame(selected)  # Pass the selected rows to a new dataframe df
delete = st.button('Delete', on_click=on_delete)
```